# Dynamically change LinearLayout height from wrap_content to fill_parent

Tags: android, dynamic, resize, android-linearlayout

If someone can please tell me where I am going wrong here that would be awesome being I have put about 2 days into trying to figure (google) it out.  Basically I just want to change the layout_height of the root linearlayout from wrap_content to fill_parent when the user clicks a button.

here is my root main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mycontainer" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="#ffff00ff">

<Button android:id="@+id/listBtn" 
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="List"
        android:onClick="listBtnHandler" 
        android:paddingLeft="17dp" 
        android:paddingRight="17dp" 
        android:layout_gravity="center" 
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my code that is triggering an error.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

private Button listBtn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    listBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.listBtn);

}


public void listBtnHandler(View v) {
    Log.i("eb", "my button worked");

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mycontainer);

    ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));



    //ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = ll.getLayoutParams();
    //params.height=300;

    //ll.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(params));

    //ll.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

}
```

}

Needless to say I can't get anything to work here.

Here is the console output and it doesn't show anything relevant since I get a source not found.

```
Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2011-12-19 15:38:15 - TestApp2] Starting activity com.xxxxx.testapp2.MainActivity on device 015ED9C002020023
[2011-12-19 15:38:15 - TestApp2] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.xxxxx.testapp2/.MainActivity }
[2011-12-19 15:38:16 - TestApp2] Attempting to connect debugger to 'com.xxxx.testapp2' on port 8600
```

Here is the error i get and what is odd is I am getting a FrameLayout.class source not found

```
// Compiled from FrameLayout.java (version 1.5 : 49.0, super bit)
@android.widget.RemoteViews.RemoteView
public class android.widget.FrameLayout extends android.view.ViewGroup {

  // Method descriptor #15 (Landroid/content/Context;)V
  // Stack: 4, Locals: 2
  public FrameLayout(android.content.Context context);
     0  aload_0 [this]
     1  aconst_null
     2  checkcast android.content.Context [1]
     5  aconst_null
     6  checkcast android.util.AttributeSet [2]
     9  iconst_0
    10  invokespecial android.view.ViewGroup(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) [3]
    13  new java.lang.RuntimeException [4]
    16  dup
    17  ldc <String "Stub!"> [5]
    19  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [6]
    22  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 16]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 23] local: this index: 0 type: android.widget.FrameLayout
        [pc: 0, pc: 23] local: context index: 1 type: android.content.Context

  // Method descriptor #23 (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)V
  // Stack: 4, Locals: 3
  public FrameLayout(android.content.Context context, android.util.AttributeSet attrs);
     0  aload_0 [this]
     1  aconst_null
     2  checkcast android.content.Context [1]
     5  aconst_null
     6  checkcast android.util.AttributeSet [2]
     9  iconst_0
    10  invokespecial android.view.ViewGroup(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) [3]
    13  new java.lang.RuntimeException [4]
    16  dup
    17  ldc <String "Stub!"> [5]
    19  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [6]
    22  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 17]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 23] local: this index: 0 type: android.widget.FrameLayout
        [pc: 0, pc: 23] local: context index: 1 type: android.content.Context
        [pc: 0, pc: 23] local: attrs index: 2 type: android.util.AttributeSet

  // Method descriptor #26 (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;I)V
  // Stack: 4, Locals: 4
  public FrameLayout(android.content.Context context, android.util.AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle);
     0  aload_0 [this]
     1  aconst_null
     2  checkcast android.content.Context [1]
     5  aconst_null
     6  checkcast android.util.AttributeSet [2]
     9  iconst_0
    10  invokespecial android.view.ViewGroup(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) [3]
    13  new java.lang.RuntimeException [4]
    16  dup
    17  ldc <String "Stub!"> [5]
    19  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [6]
    22  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 18]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 23] local: this index: 0 type: android.widget.FrameLayout
        [pc: 0, pc: 23] local: context index: 1 type: android.content.Context
        [pc: 0, pc: 23] local: attrs index: 2 type: android.util.AttributeSet
        [pc: 0, pc: 23] local: defStyle index: 3 type: int

  // Method descriptor #30 (I)V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 2
  public void setForegroundGravity(int foregroundGravity);
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [4]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [5]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [6]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 19]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.widget.FrameLayout
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: foregroundGravity index: 1 type: int

  // Method descriptor #33 (Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;)Z
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 2
  protected boolean verifyDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable who);
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [4]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [5]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [6]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 20]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.widget.FrameLayout
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: who index: 1 type: android.graphics.drawable.Drawable

  // Method descriptor #37 ()V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  protected void drawableStateChanged();
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [4]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [5]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [6]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 21]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.widget.FrameLayout

  // Method descriptor #39 ()Landroid/widget/FrameLayout$LayoutParams;
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  protected android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams();
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [4]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [5]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [6]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 22]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.widget.FrameLayout

  // Method descriptor #41 (Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;)V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 2
  public void setForeground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable drawable);
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [4]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [5]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [6]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 23]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.widget.FrameLayout
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: drawable index: 1 type: android.graphics.drawable.Drawable

  // Method descriptor #44 ()Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  public android.graphics.drawable.Drawable getForeground();
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [4]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [5]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [6]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 24]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.widget.FrameLayout

  // Method descriptor #46 (II)V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 3
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec);
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [4]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [5]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [6]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 25]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.widget.FrameLayout
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: widthMeasureSpec index: 1 type: int
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: heightMeasureSpec index: 2 type: int

  // Method descriptor #50 (ZIIII)V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 6
  protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom);
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [4]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [5]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [6]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 26]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.widget.FrameLayout
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: changed index: 1 type: boolean
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: left index: 2 type: int
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: top index: 3 type: int
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: right index: 4 type: int
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: bottom index: 5 type: int

  // Method descriptor #58 (IIII)V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 5
  protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh);
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [4]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [5]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [6]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 27]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.widget.FrameLayout
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: w index: 1 type: int
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: h index: 2 type: int
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: oldw index: 3 type: int
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: oldh index: 4 type: int

  // Method descriptor #64 (Landroid/graphics/Canvas;)V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 2
  public void draw(android.graphics.Canvas canvas);
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [4]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [5]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [6]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 28]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.widget.FrameLayout
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: canvas index: 1 type: android.graphics.Canvas

  // Method descriptor #68 (Landroid/graphics/Region;)Z
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 2
  public boolean gatherTransparentRegion(android.graphics.Region region);
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [4]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [5]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [6]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 29]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.widget.FrameLayout
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: region index: 1 type: android.graphics.Region

  // Method descriptor #72 (Z)V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 2
  public void setMeasureAllChildren(boolean measureAll);
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [4]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [5]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [6]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 30]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.widget.FrameLayout
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: measureAll index: 1 type: boolean

  // Method descriptor #75 ()Z
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  public boolean getConsiderGoneChildrenWhenMeasuring();
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [4]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [5]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [6]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 31]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.widget.FrameLayout

  // Method descriptor #77 (Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)Landroid/widget/FrameLayout$LayoutParams;
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 2
  public android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(android.util.AttributeSet attrs);
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [4]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [5]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [6]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 32]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.widget.FrameLayout
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: attrs index: 1 type: android.util.AttributeSet

  // Method descriptor #80 (Landroid/view/ViewGroup$LayoutParams;)Z
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 2
  protected boolean checkLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams p);
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [4]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [5]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [6]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 33]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.widget.FrameLayout
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: p index: 1 type: android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams

  // Method descriptor #83 (Landroid/view/ViewGroup$LayoutParams;)Landroid/view/ViewGroup$LayoutParams;
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 2
  protected android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams p);
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [4]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [5]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [6]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 34]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.widget.FrameLayout
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: p index: 1 type: android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams

  // Method descriptor #84 ()Landroid/view/ViewGroup$LayoutParams;
  // Stack: 1, Locals: 1
  protected bridge synthetic android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams();
    0  aload_0 [this]
    1  invokevirtual android.widget.FrameLayout.generateDefaultLayoutParams() : android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams [7]
    4  areturn
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 3]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 5] local: this index: 0 type: android.widget.FrameLayout

  // Method descriptor #85 (Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)Landroid/view/ViewGroup$LayoutParams;
  // Stack: 2, Locals: 2
  public bridge synthetic android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(android.util.AttributeSet x0);
    0  aload_0 [this]
    1  aload_1 [x0]
    2  invokevirtual android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(android.util.AttributeSet) : android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams [8]
    5  areturn
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 3]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 6] local: this index: 0 type: android.widget.FrameLayout
        [pc: 0, pc: 6] local: x0 index: 1 type: android.util.AttributeSet

  Inner classes:
    [inner class info: #11 android/widget/FrameLayout$LayoutParams, outer class info: #9 android/widget/FrameLayout
     inner name: #12 LayoutParams, accessflags: 9 public static],
    [inner class info: #79 android/view/ViewGroup$LayoutParams, outer class info: #10 android/view/ViewGroup
     inner name: #12 LayoutParams, accessflags: 9 public static],
    [inner class info: #90 android/widget/RemoteViews$RemoteView, outer class info: #105 android/widget/RemoteViews
     inner name: #91 RemoteView, accessflags: 9737 public abstract static]
}
```

Comment: Is that layout set on your activity content view before calling this method?

Comment: Yes the activity loads up and shows the button.  I update the code above to show the whole activity.  Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you are calling the right `LinearLayout` then try to call `invalidate()` on your `LinearLayout` after setting the new `LayoutParams`

Comment: I actually get a exception ClassCastException that references a FrameLayout but I don't have a FrameLayout in my xml unless the activity itself puts my xml in a FrameLayout

Comment: Can you put the log here so we can help you ?

Comment: No problem, are you sure that is the console log output? It looks strange

Comment: You are getting "Application already deployed. No need to reinstall." on the first line, try to uninstall the app, rebuild the project and run it again :)

Comment: Its probably because I didn't change anything but I did as you said and uninstalled, cleaned, and reinstall and I still get the source not found error for FrameLayout.class

Comment: I am using API 10 for 2.3.3 could that have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project. Classic one.

Comment: Just tried cleaning, didn't help thanks. Not sure why i am getting a source not found error.  I even browse to the sdk and select the android.jar but I get " The source attachment does not contain the source for the file FrameLayout.class when I am not even using a FrameLayout in my project.